# Javascript Function Opens URLs with Https but fails to open URL's with just domain and not HTTPs or www prefix

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

I am creating a JavaScript function which opens all listed URLs in bulk which seems to work fine with URL's having "https" like https://google.com but, the same URLs in form: google.com shows an error.

The following is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">    
<textarea class="form_area" name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols=72 rows="10"></textarea>    
<div class="button_opener"><input value="Open All!" class="submit button button-large font-weight-semibold button-rounded ls0 nott m-0" type="button" onClick="open_all();"></div><div class="button_opener"><input type="reset" value="Clear!" class="button button-large font-weight-semibold button-rounded ls0 nott m-0"></div></form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
function open_all(){
var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
var urls = urls.split('\n');
var totalno = urls.length;
var s;
for(var i=0;i<totalno;i++){
s = urls[i];
if(s){
if(s.substr(0,7)!='http://') 
    {
    s = ''+s;
    }
window.open(s);
}
}
return false;
}
</script>
```

I can't figure out how to make the function work with all kinds of URL formats like: https://google.com, https://www.google.com and google.com

Also, the urls are opened in reverse order i.e. the URLs at the bottom of form are opened first where the URLs should open from top to bottom order.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Most pop up blockers will prevent you from opening up multiple windows. I guess you have yours disabled.

Comment: I am aware about popups and will prompt users to disable popup blocker on the website. Just cannot figure out that pointed http and https error. I appened that which makes the urls open with https but not without https

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I don't see any, its just when I enter a URL without HTTPS:// it shows a 404 error

Comment: Am i allowed to share my live url here?

Comment: So what is the url in the address bar of the window? Is it a url on your domain becuase window.open sees it as a relative url?

Comment: https://www.prourlopener.com/www.thefontworld.com/block-text-generator

This is the URL in address bar when I add a URL: thefontworld.com which should open at https://thefontworld.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the "error" is exactly, but if you want to add a check for http:// or https:// then a simple reg exp can do it.

```js
function open_all() {
  var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
  var urls = urls.split('\n');
  var totalno = urls.length;
  var s;
  for (var i = 0; i < totalno; i++) {
    s = urls[i].trim();
    if (s) {
      if (s.substr(0, 7) != 'http://') {
        s = '' + s;
      }
      if(!s.match(/(https?:)?\/\//)){
        s = "https://" + s;
      }
      // window.open(s);
      console.log(s);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <textarea class="form_area" name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols=72 rows="10">http://example.com/1
http://example.com/2
//example.com/3
example.com/4
</textarea>
  <div class="button_opener"><input value="Open All!" class="submit button button-large font-weight-semibold button-rounded ls0 nott m-0" type="button" onClick="open_all();"></div>
  <div class="button_opener"><input type="reset" value="Clear!" class="button button-large font-weight-semibold button-rounded ls0 nott m-0"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: On the live website, it doesn't seem to be working infact the open button doesn't work at all.

Comment: Nevermind, added window.open(s); and it's working now